# Do I have to use twig with Silex?

Tags: php, html, twig, silex

Do I have to use Twig to render views in Silex or am I able to render views and code them via pure PHP rather than a template engine? If so, how would I go about doing it?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you not just echo / print contents instead of use the render engine to render the twigs?

Answer (score 0):

No, silex does not force you to use twig, or mandate any template engine at all for that matter.

Generally the way you'd use a template engine (or any library) with silex is:

- Add the library to your `composer.json` to install it.
- Set up that library with the silex DI container. If a pre-packaged silex service provider exists, you can use that to wire it up in the container.
- Access the templating service, either by fetching it from the container yourself, or by defining a service that receives that service as a constructor argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
return $sometext;
```

Or, if you need to return a non-200 status code, do:

```
return new Response($sometext, $statusCode);
```